# Opening form from combo box in another form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form called DisplayForm.  In that form is a combo box drop down that is at the top of column on the form where a label would usually go. I want to select an item from that drop down menu and use that bit of data to open another form. I have copied an example from the web, changed the names and can't get it to work. Here is the code;

```
If Not Me.NewRecord Then
DoCmd.OpenForm "AreaForm", _
    WhereCondition:="LArea=" & Me.AreaCBDrop
End If
```

Area is the name of the field in the query that is the recordsource for the form, but when I run it, it opens a msgbox that wants me to enter a peramater value. I also don't understand what the IF is about. I have tried this with and without the if but get the same result. Me.AreaCBDrop has the correct value in it, but the where does not work.

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: Is Me.AreaCBDrop a numeric value? Is the field `LArea` a numeric field?

Comment: Neither is numeric.  They are both text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` condition is expecting a text parameter, but you are not supplying the expected format, so it is asking for one.

Surround your `Me.AreaCBDrop` with single quotes, like this:

```
If Not Me.NewRecord Then
DoCmd.OpenForm "AreaForm", _
    WhereCondition:="LArea='" & Me.AreaCBDrop & "'"
End If
```

Comment: Worked like a Champ.  Thank you so much.